# How to get a 2 row output in a single line in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to get the single line output from the below query output

```
select @@hostname,count(*) "RECOMMENDED_PATCHES" from test.PATCHES
union all
select @@hostname,count(*) "PATCH_VERSIONS" from test.PATCH_VERSIONS

output:
ct-test-02 79
ct-test-02 0

expected output:
ct-test-02 79 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select @@hostname,  
(select count(*) from test.PATCHES) "RECOMMENDED_PATCHES",  
(select count(*) from test.PATCH_VERSIONS) "PATCH_VERSIONS"
```

Comment: getting ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: I have edited my answer, please can you try it again?

Comment: super tim it worked